# Play console Pre-launch report not working with Android App Bundle

Tags: android, google-play-console, android-app-bundle, app-bundle

I try to upload an app-bundle for testing on Beta track in Google Play Console and as a result in pre-launch report section in STABILITY tab it says `"This device could not be tested at this time. Please upload a new APK."` for most devices.
Testing goes well when uploading a normal apk file.
Doesn't it work yet with app-bundles or does it requires some additional settings?
Thanks for help!

Comment: Please reach out to the Play Console developer support team so we can look more closely at the issue here. Also, is that for all devices or only a few. If a few, would you mind sharing the list?

Comment: Galaxy S3 Samsung Android 4.3 - the only device with some exception information on 'Test result details' section, and for all other it says - "This device could not be tested at this time. Please upload a new APK."

Comment: Note that many other apps successfully publish App Bundles and use the pre-launch report, so this needs to be looked at closer, but only the support team can help where you can share your app and they can look at logs and details.

Comment: Just added support for app bundles, and same issue! I am using my previous private key to sign, not an upload key. Not sure if that is why? None of the devices works for me, all show the device could not be tested at this time.

Comment: i have similar issue, asking google already